# How to extract the SID string?

Tags: assembly

I have found the following in a trojan sample. First, it gets the token of the current process and then it calls the `GetTokenInformation()` API with `TokenGroups` as `InfoClass` parameter. So, it puts the TOKEN_GROUPS structure to a certain place. Later, it uses the `AllocateAndInitializeSid()` API with the following parameters:

```
      PUSH EAX
      PUSH EBX
      PUSH EBX
      PUSH EBX
      PUSH EBX
      PUSH EBX
      PUSH EBX
      PUSH 220
      PUSH 20
      PUSH 2
      LEA EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EBP - C]
      PUSH EAX
      CALL DWORD PTR DS:[&ADVAPI32.AllocateAndInitializeSid]
```

So, is the SID string S-1-20-220 ? If not, how I can extract this?

Note: Some lines later, the trojan compares this SID with the SID values from the TOKEN_GROUPS structure using using the `EqualSid()` API. I mean, it accesses the 2nd field of TOKEN_GROUPS structure which is an array that consists of SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES structures. Each of these structures has a SID field which is compared with the initialized SID. For that reason, I would like to know how the initialized SID looks like.

best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the documentation for `AllocateAndInitializeSid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375213):

```
  PUSH EAX ; pSid
  PUSH EBX ; dwSubAuthority7
  PUSH EBX ; dwSubAuthority6
  PUSH EBX ; dwSubAuthority5
  PUSH EBX ; dwSubAuthority4
  PUSH EBX ; dwSubAuthority3
  PUSH EBX ; dwSubAuthority2
  PUSH 220 ; dwSubAuthority1
  PUSH 20  ; dwSubAuthority0
  PUSH 2   ; nSubAuthorityCount
  LEA EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EBP - C]
  PUSH EAX ; pIdentifierAuthority
  CALL DWORD PTR DS:[&ADVAPI32.AllocateAndInitializeSid]
```

I'm guessing that `EBX` was set to `0`, so this is effectively the following snippet from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379620(v=vs.85).aspx:

[image: Snippet]

The SID for `BUILTIN\Administrators` is `S-1-5-32-544`.